# G Suite Email Migration Does Not Complete, Stuck on 99%

Tags: email, admin, imap, data-migration, google-workspace

I'm currently experiencing something rather weird: while migrating emails from a GoDaddy email server to a new G Suite set up for a number of users, I was able to successfully move for a couple of emails, as confirmed by Google's 'Complete' tick beside them. I was able to observe the migration too as it went on.

However, for one of the emails, the number of emails read just seems to keep increasing, and it still hasn't displayed 'Complete', but remains stuck on '99%'.

See screenshots I literally took just now below: as of the first latest screenshot, it says '*Successfully migrated **3230** emails*', while stuck on 99%:

[image: 3230 emails, 99%]

Then I hit refresh, check the status of that same account, and now it says '*...**3250** emails*', *while still stuck on 99%*:

[image: 3250 emails, 99%]

This isn't how it's supposed to behave, at least that isn't the behaviour I experienced with the previous 4 emails in that list. Ideally, it should say '*Migrating **X** out of **fixed_amount** emails*'. In this case, that **fixed_amount** was 
**about 2,000 emails**. It has now since passed that figure, but instead of showing 'Complete', it instead shows '*Successfully migrated **new_amount***' where **new_amount** keeps increasing.

This has been ongoing for almost 24 hours now. Honestly, I don't know if this is a bug or not. I really just need some helpful info to know if I should be concerned or not, perhaps maybe if someone else has run into this. Anyone?

Answer (score 7):

Stumbled on to Google's documentation: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7032598?hl=en

To quote the '**Why does my migration look like it's stuck at 99%?**' section:

> You’ll see 99% when all email is migrated. After everything is
>   migrated, the data migration service applies any labels to the
>   migrated email, which can take time. When the labels are applied, you
>   should see that the migration is complete (100%).
>
> You might also see this issue if the estimated number of emails to
>   migrate exceeds the actual number of messages. The migration will
>   report 99% until the migration completes. This process might take some
>   time.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be concerned. I was migrating around 29.000 emails from a personal gmail to Google Workspace gmail and the migration took 4 days (migrating only one user), from which the last 1.5 days the migration was "stuck" at 99%. No need to restart the migration, eventually it indeed finishes. I also got several error codes (e.g. 17009 - 'Generating an access token with the supplied credentials was unsuccessful...'), but none proved valid, I haven't actioned on them as, like in your case, I saw the number of migrated emails increasing.

Comment: It took 7 days for my mail (100k emails) to reach 99%. It's now been at 99% for a month...

Comment: @Daniel has it completed?

Comment: It did! It took 9 weeks but it did finish successfully.